# Customise WSO2 IoT with my IP

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I can not understand how to modify WSO2 with its own IP address and no longer have localhost.

Can someone explain?

Thank you for your help.

Tof

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the carbon.xml file in wso2iot-3.0.0/core/repository/conf location and change the following tags with the IP Address.

```
<HostName>192.168.10.1</HostName>

<MgtHostName>192.168.10.1</MgtHostName>
```

Restart the server to apply the changes.

Comment: Thank you but it still does not work. I knew this operation. When I want to access devicemgt, when I go to the link 192.168.10.1:9443/devicemgt here is what I have: First of all it redirects to: Https://192.168.1.10.1:9443 devicemgt/uuf/login?Referer=/ And it ends on: localhost:9443/samlsso – Tof 42 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

[WSO2 IoT 3.1.0](http://wso2.com/iot/) is released now, and we have included a script to change the localhost URL to an IP. Please check in the [WSO2 IoT-3.1.0]/scripts/change-ip.sh. When you run this, it will configure the server to use the IP instead of the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing below configurations

1) comment Hostname and MgtHostName Field in carbon.xml

2) replace all the localhost with IP in sso-idp-config.xml

3) core/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/devicemgt/app/conf/app-conf.json
        "identityProviderUrl" : "https://IP:9443/samlsso",
        "acs": "https://IP:9443/devicemgt/uuf/sso/acs",

4) core/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/api-store/site/conf/site.json
        "identityProviderURL" : "https://IP:9443/samlsso",

5) core/repository/conf/app-manager.xml

Under SSO-configuration set "identityProviderURL" : "https://IP:9443/samlsso"

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I found that in /bin/wso2server.sh environment variables were used They are to be parameterized at the end of the file /bin/wso2server.sh Hoping it helps other people

Answer (score 0):

Complete list at docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS300/Configuring+WSO2+IoT+Server+with+the+IP

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS300/Configuring+WSO2+IoT+Server+with+the+IP